# Javascript Type Error (intermediate value).timeout is not a function

Tags: node.js

I'm getting a

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).timeout is not a function
    at refreshPricelist (C:\afl-online-api-dev\refreshPricelist.js:36:8)
    at <anonymous>
```

Referencing the following  code:

```
    console.log("Pricelist already processing... setting up listener");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      plEmitter.once(`pl_${accountID}`, () => {
        console.log("resolved");
        return resolve();
      });
    }).timeout(5000);
```

The research I've done so far is telling me that there's an incorrect semicolon somewhere but I've plopped this into an es-linter and it's looking alright minus the console logging. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: `timeout()` is not a method of `Promise` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeout` is not a method of Promise Object. Maybe your code/lib/app want to use a package named [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) that add some features to native promises.

So you have to do
`npm install bluebird --save`

then in the head of your javascript file

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are chaining a `timeout` function to a `Promise` object. As far as I know a`Promise` object has not such a method.
What does this `timeout` function do?

Comment: The timeout() function comes with Bluebird promises and rejects the promise after a certain number of milliseconds. I didn't assign the Bluebird library (which includes a timeout function) to replace the default Promises. I did that and the issue is fixed.

Comment: I didn't know about bluebird library.